# Prevent user from submitting record until a certain condition is met?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I posted a question about this yesterday but did not get a response.

The question was whether there is a way to integrate jQuery with a gridview control to prevent user from submitting a record until the length is atleast 10.

I have managed to modify the code to work but it is not working correctly.

This version below highlights a cell if the user enters a value that is less than 10. This is good. However, it still does not prevent user from submitting the form.

Any ideas how to modify it to both highlight the cell as it is doing but also prevent user from submitting the form.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".txtsourceincome").blur(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().length < 10) {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                    $(this).css("color", "white");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                    $(this).css("color", "black");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

'//update:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".txtsourceincome").blur(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().length < 10) {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                    $(this).css("color", "white");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                    $(this).css("color", "black");
                }
            });
            $(".btnNext").click(function () {
                var result = true;
                $(".txtsourceincome").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().length < 10) {
                        result = false;
                        alert("Input should be minimum of 10 characters or blank");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try binding a click event to the submit button and do a `preventDefault()` on it?

Comment: @gaganshera, I have bound it to button click but it still doesn't prevent it from submitting. Please see updated code.

Comment: Use `preventDefault()` using the event object `e` from `$(".btnNext").click(function (e) {`. Like `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @gaganshera, thank you. Got it working now. I removed the preventDefault and just added css class to the button click event.

`cssClass="btnNext"` and now it works fine.

Comment: Can I post this as the correct answer? Or had you tried binding the click event to the submit button before my suggestion? Just asking :)

Comment: @gaganshera, sorry I am just getting back to this.

You can although, your solution did not work for me as I indicated when I tried using it that way. I don't see my comment about using preventDefault. The error I got was that preventDefault is not supported. Perhaps it is because of the way I used.

Comment: You shouldn't get the preventDefault not supported error. Anyway as long as your code works. :) I guess you should post your own answer if that worked.